# Help with proof by induction problem

Tags: calculus, analysis, induction, proof-explanation

Any input on this problem I'm working on?

I want to prove by induction that for all natural $n$ we have that

$\sum_{i=1}^n -1^jj^2 = (-1)^n\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

So far I have:

1) Proved the base case, n = 1, which gives me:

$\sum_{i=1}^n -1^jj^2 = (-1)\frac{2}{2}$

$\rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^n -1^jj^2 = -1$

Which makes sense.

2) For the induction step, I assume n = k is true, I get:

$\sum_{i=1}^n -1^jj^2 = (-1)^k\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$

Then I want to find out if this is true for n = k+1. I insert for k+1.

$\sum_{i=1}^n -1^jj^2 = (-1)^k+1\frac{k+1((k+1)+1)}{2}$

I know you guys usually ask for me making an effort at it, but I am literally stuck, and have been so for some time. Any tips?

BTW I have read [this guide](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/why-are-induction-proofs-so-challenging-for-students), which was a good read, but didn't really help me figuring out how to solve these. Please share other links if you have any.

Comment: Please post your problem here with appropriate formatting in MathJax (tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of linking to an image of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of alternating sign squares of integers stuck with proof by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411302/sum-of-alternating-sign-squares-of-integers-stuck-with-proof-by-induction)

Comment: Split into 2 cases: n odd , n even.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}(-1)^j j^2 = \left[\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^j j^2\right] + (-1)^{k+1}(k+1)^2.$$

Now you can use the assumption on the bracketed term.

You may need to consider even and odd $k$ separately.

(Note:  I'm not sure $-1^k$ and $(-1)^k$ are the same thing.  The second one makes it clear what you mean.)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are,

Assume:
$\sum_{i=1}^k -1^jj^2 = (-1)^k\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$

Using the hypothesis show that:

$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} -1^jj^2 = (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k+1((k+1)+1)}{2}$

the part you are missing:

$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} -1^jj^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^{k} -1^jj^2) + (-1)^{k+1}(k+1)^2$

Now substitute based on the inductive hypothesis.  Apply your algebra skills and take it home.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}(-1)^j j^2=(-1)^{k+1}(k+1)^2+\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^j j^2=(-1)^{k+1}(k+1)^2+(-1)^k\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
therefore
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}(-1)^j j^2=(-1)^{k+1}\left((k+1)^2-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)$$
$$\qquad=(-1)^{k+1}\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with induction proofs, the usual strategy is to try to find some way to reduce the expression we get when inserting $n=k+1$ to the expression when $n=k$ so we can apply the assertion given by the inductive step and then work from there.

If the expression in question is a sum (as it is the case) it is straightforward to to just that, as we can pop the last term of the summation to get the expression when $n=k$.

Thus:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (-1)^jj^2 = (-1)^{k+1}(k+1)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{k} -1^jj^2= (-1)^{k+1}(k+1)^2 + (-1)^k\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
$$

Now it is a matter of applying algebra.