# Is there an error in this proof by induction problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I was asked to show by induction that " $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},-1 \cdot3+2\cdot 5-3\cdot7+...+2n(4n+1)= \alpha n $" and find the value of the constant $\alpha$.

First, I rewrote the sum on the left side as $$ \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^{k}\cdot k(2k+1)$$

Next, I tried to check the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ in order to find the constant, but here is where my problem arises. For $n=1$ the value of the sum is 7, for $n=2$ is 22 and for $n=3$ the result is 45. Due to the above, it's impossible that this follows a linear partial sum for 2n. Am I correct or am I missing something?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: In your sum, the second factor $k+1$ should be $2k+1$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about $\alpha=4n+3$?

Comment: In any case, you are correct that a sum like yours will not result simplify into $\alpha n$ for some scalar $\alpha$.  It will happen to be quadratic.  You might consider splitting the sum into two to prove this: $2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k\cdot k^2 + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^kk$.  If you look around you can find posts [like this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411302/sum-of-alternating-sign-squares-of-integers-stuck-with-proof-by-induction) for each of those individual sums and them simplify.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The problem statement says "*constant $\alpha$*"

Comment: @JMoravitz The part about "constant" was not in the original version of the question  but was edited in later.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: Alternatively, you can group each negative term with the immediately following positive term. That simplifies things down to an easy summation.

Comment: Thank you all, I think I'll just send an email to the teacher's assistant about this.