# Combinations in Arithmetic progression?

Tags: arithmetic

My question actually come from this:

[Intuitively understanding $\sum_{i=1}^ni={n+1\choose2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273112/intuitively-understanding-sum-i-1ni-n1-choose2)

I was once examining the sum of an A.P series with first term $a$ and common difference $d$ . And this question mentioned above reminded me of same.

$S_n=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)=a n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}d=a \cdot\;^{n}C_1+\;^{n}C_{2} \cdot d$

Is there any special significance or intuition behind this result? Why does those combinations appear? can it be extended? Or it's pure coincidence?

Comment: Hint. You have separated the sums of the $a$ terms and the $d$ terms. Now think about $\sum_1^n (a + bi + ci^2)$. That might give you a generalization - maybe not the one you expect.

Comment: Ah I know, it's quite similar to the case taking $a$ and $d$ common but i have wanted to know is there any other way of seeing it, maybe in terms of choosing $a$'s and $d$'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression for an A.P. follows easily from the expression for the sum of numbers from $1$ to $n$:

$$S_n \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( a+(k-1)d \right)$$
We can break up the sum, that is, take out the $a$ part and treat it separately.

$$S_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( a \right) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( (k-1)d \right)$$

The first term is easy; you add $n$ copies of a constant to get $na$.  We can pull the constant $d$ outside the second sum:

$$S_n =na + d\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( (k-1) \right) = na + d\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left( j \right)$$

Finally, we apply our sum of integers formula $\sum_{j=0}^m j =  \sum_{j=1}^m j = \binom{m+1}{2}$ to get

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left( j \right) = \binom{(n-1)+1}{2} $$
So
$$
S_n = an + d\binom{n}{2} =  a\binom{n}{1} + d\binom{n}{2} 
$$

This can be extended for sequences where the first difference is itself an arithmetic progression, for example, 
$$2+3+6+ 11+ 18 + 27 +\cdots $$
in which case there will now be an additional term in the answer involving  $\binom{n}{3} $.